# jquery selector on razor does not trigger event

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, razor

Can you please suggest if below code  triggers a jquery onchange event will it work?

```
<div id= "abc">
</div>

@Html.Partial("partial.cshtml")
```

Inside partial view there are a lot of nested dom elements and one of them is a

```
<select id="xyz">
</select>
```

I am trying to call a jquery onchange event like this but it does not work

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
   $("#abc").find("#xyz").on("change",function(){
   alert("hi");
});
});
```

the onchnage event just does not trigger.

Comment: hi David.. thanks for response. Yes i have been trying to get this to trigger since last  hours but it just does not trigger.. I used the visual studio debugger and when the page loads i can see the function gets registered although nothing alerts. As per my understanding if this code is correct then when i make a selection the onchange should trigger.. I dont know how to trigger this and how to debug

Answer (score 1):

the .find() function will look for matching children of the element you're selecting, but in reality, you are looking for a "sibling" element that is a sibling of your 'abc' div. One solution is that you can call .siblings() to find that sibling element and then add an event listener for the onchange event:

```
$('#abc').siblings('#xyz').on('change', function() {
    alert("Changes");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The HTML structure you're demonstrating is:

```
<div id="abc">
</div>
<select id="xyz">
</select>
```

These elements are siblings, one does not contain the other.  But in the jQuery code you're looking for one element within the other:

```
$("#abc").find("#xyz")
```

So the latter is never found, because it's not contained within the former.  However, since the selector is using an `id`, you don't have to narrow it down to a containing element in the first place.  You can just select based on the `id`:

```js
$("#xyz").on("change",function(){
    alert("hi");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="abc">
</div>
<select id="xyz">
    <option value="0">0</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
</select>
```

Comment: actually i want to select #xyz inside #abc only.. #xyz which is a partial view is a reusable component which is used in many places inside the application. I dont want to change behavior of those.. only when i use it inside my div #abc it should do the alert.

Comment: @kimi86: But your `#xyz` element *isn't* inside of your `#abc` element.  At least not in the code you're showing.  So if you *only* want to select one which is inside of `#abc` then your code is currently working and is successfully finding zero matching elements.  It also sounds like you're claiming to be re-using the same `xyz` value on multiple element `id`s, which is invalid HTML and renders the behavior of the JavaScript undefined.  `id` values need to be unique within the document.